# Reverse Engineering ELF Patches

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiling, ota, ida

I have an OTA patch which according to the source code of it's vendor (OpenSource) seems to be generated by Red Hat coreutils and it's an ELF binary.
Using IDA Pro, I can see a lot of nullsub and segments in the binary, but my goal is to reverse this patch to have something like the Android patches from google, clean and nice *.p segments. In other words, I would like to "decompile" the elf patch while there is no real subroutines (It's a patch!).

I am not looking for a solution, would appreciate any brain storming ideas how can I make sense of this elf binary.

Comment: You could try to look at reverse engineering stack exchange: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @teoreda I've just done. Tx